# How to use global URL params to filter content in Next.js without messing up routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have want to have a URL structure that looks like this:

- example.com/products
- example.com/hiking/products
- example.com/driving/products

---

- example.com/news
- example.com/hiking/news
- example.com/driving/news

Where I have a URL param that filters the content shown on the website without "routing" the user somewhere else. The params are only there as a sort of global filter of content, the website layout doesnt change, only the content. So no "filter" just means show everything, hiking means show only products with the "hiking" tag etc.

The reason I want to do it like this across the entire site is so that I can send a specific URL to a customer with filters already in place.

Solutions:

- This can be done with query params, but the links will look very ugly and I want this to be global on the site, so not only the products page, but also the blog/news etc. Having to send query params on every link is not an options for us.
- This can also be done by using the Next.js dynamic slugs, however I dont see a solution that doesnt require pretty much a duplicate of files.

I want this to work similarly to Next.js locales, where it can basically just prefix `example.com/en-US/...` to every URL without messing with the routing.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:
Another solution would be to repurpose locales to do this for me, however I'm already using locales for its intended purpose :D

Comment: _"can also be done by using the Next.js dynamic slugs, however I dont see a solution that doesnt require pretty much a duplicate of files"_ - have you looked into dynamic [catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)? They would seem to fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably switch the dynamic routes around. Would something like this work for you?

- /products
- /products/hiking
- /products/driving
- /news
- /news/hiking
- /news/driving

This way your folder structure would look like this:

```
- products
--- [category].tsx

- news
--- [category].tsx
```

The `[category].tsx` files would contain the code related to their respective folder (news, products, etc.), so you wouldn't have any duplicate files.

If for some reason you need to retain your current page structure, you could use nested dynamic routes, but based on your description I can't think of a good reason why you wouldn't be able to structure it like this.

Comment: Swapping them around might be an option. It would be cleaner to have it prefixed like locales considering the entire site would change to match the filter, but this might be the best option at the moment.

Comment: You could just as easily do `[category]/news.tsx`, `[category]/products.tsx` and use a separate `news.tsx` for the root page. If you put all the page logic in a component, you wouldn't really duplicate much code either.

Comment: Yeah this is the way I'm doing it currently, however I was hoping there would be a "cooler" way to do it in Next.js considering locales works in a similar way. Thanks for the help though :D